# Why there are no resources (RAM and CPU) dedicated only for administrators' access?

Tags: linux, resources, limit

I've been a user of multiple Linux servers (in multiple organizations) for some time; however, I am not an expert.
What I've noticed is that users will, from time to time, accidentally do analysis that will consume all server resources, and administrators will have no other option but to restart the server. **My question is, why there is no limit (as a threshold) that splits users' access (for analysis), and administrators' access (to manage server and resolve problems)?** For example, if a server has 256GM of RAM and 64 cores, why 1GB (or 512MB, or 256MB or whatever small amount needed to open a terminal and kill a problematic process) and 1 core couldn't be accessible only to administrators, and the rest to users'?

I know that some answers will be "well, you paid for 256GB and 64 cores, but you use 255GB and 63 cores for the life of a server". I am aware of that argument, but I am asking why this feature is not implemented as a convenience; for example when I am managing my own personal server, and I really don't care about those unused 1GB and 1 core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have never had a system so busy I could not ssh into it. I have had systems that oom, and kill ssh, and other useful services. You should be able to use your cpu at 100 percent, and still ssh in. I would try to investigate exactly what is happening when your system because unresponsive. Maybe the logs will have answers for you.

I have never had to use it but ulimit is what you want. Some distros have a admin group and others don't. Put your none admin user in a group, and limit their resources accordingly.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ulimit-soft-limits-and-hard-limits-in-linux/